# How to solve a circular class dependency with shared base class without headers?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, circular-dependency

So I am creating a project that involves having vectors nested inside one another, but the structure won't compile. I think this is a case of circular dependency, but all  of the fixes I've seen seem to only apply to code involving header files and separate translation units.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A();
};

// The following forward declaration statements didn't solve the
// compiler error:
// class C;
// class C : public A;

class B : public A {
    std::vector<A*> Avector;    
public:
    void addC(C* Cin){Avector.push_back(Cin);}
    ~B();
};

class C : public A {
    std::vector<A*> Avector;        
public:
    void addB(B* Bin){Avector.push_back(Bin);}
    ~C();
};

int main() {
    B b;
    C c;
    b.addC(&c);
    c.addB(&b);
}
```

I've tried forward declaring with

```
class C;
Class C : public A;
```

But none of it seems to work.

The error I get is:

```
\test\test\source.cpp(15): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'C'
\test\test\source.cpp(15): error C2065: 'Cin' : undeclared identifier
```

Is this sort of code implementable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"... but all  of the fixes I've seen seem to only apply to code involving header files and separate translation units."*

I well agree that a popular Q&A like **[Resolve circular dependencies in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c)** doesn't really answer your question how to handle this within a single implementation file (header or not).

However IMHO it's considered the better practice (and as you could pick up by [these pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5Dcircular%20dependency)), to separate out class declarations in headers and implementation/definition into their own translation units.
Even with header only (e.g. template class) libraries, you should consider to provide a separate class declaration (without inlined code), and provide the implementation in a separate source file, that's included there.

Your problem is actually here:

```
class B : public A {
    // ...
    void addC(C* Cin) { Avector.push_back(Cin); }
                   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
};
```

At this point (even with a forward declaration of `class C;`) the compiler doesn't know how to convert `C*` to `A*`, because the information about the inheritance relationship is missing (and no, you can't make forward declarations like `class C : public A;`).

> *"Is this sort of code implementable?"*

**You can do all that in a single translation unit/header file:**

Instead of inlining the function definition with `B`'s class declaration, you should separate it out to be seen after the full declaration of `class C`:

```
class C;

class B : public A {
    // ...
    void addC(C* Cin);
};

class C : public A {
    // ...
};

inline void B::addC(C* Cin) { Avector.push_back(Cin); }
```

`class C` will see the full declaration of `class B` anyway (because of declaration order). Thus it's OK to use the implementation

```
void addB(B* Bin) { Avector.push_back(Bin); }
```

from within the `class C` declaration.

Comment: No need to put the definition in an other compilation unit. definition of `B::AddC` should be after `C` definition.

Comment: It seems that all the code of OP is in a single translation unit, so no, it is not required. If the code was in header file, yes.

Comment: You beautiful people, thank you very much. Is there a way to share the credit for an answer?

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, so I've added this to my fix, it wouldn't harm in either case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd tried forward declaring, and I'd tried putting the function implementation after the second part, but I hadn't tried both at once. The fixed code for anyone googling this 10 years later:

```
  #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>

    using namespace std;

    class C;

    class A
    {
    public:
        virtual ~A();
    };

    class B : public A
    {
    public:
        vector<A*> Avector;

        void addC(C* Cin);
        ~B();
    };

    class C : public A
    {
    public:
        vector<A*> Avector;

        void addB(B* Bin)
        {
            Avector.push_back(Bin);

        };
            ~C();
        };

    void B::addC(C* Cin)
    {
        Avector.push_back(Cin);
    }

    int main()
    {

    }
```

My thanks to πάντα ῥεῖ , and a shout out to Jarod42.

Comment: You don't need to post an answer again. That you marked mine accepted, already states you solved the problem on behalf of it (I also added some small improvements).